# Extra space from a singlespaced float

Tags: spacing, floats

I want a singlespaced table/figure but other-spaced text. When I put a table in between two paragraphs and it floats off, there is an extra space when I use a global in the preamble "\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\singlespacing}" OR encase the table inside a singlespace environment (as in example table 1). I get the desired spacing if I simply put "\singlespacing" inside the table (as in example table 2).

I'd prefer a preamble solution as I have many of these in different environments (table/minipage/figure/etc).

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{lipsum,setspace}
%\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\singlespacing}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-8]

\lipsum[1][1-8]

\begin{singlespace}
\begin{table}[htbp]\caption{Table}
\lipsum[1][1-12]
\lipsum[1][1-12]
\lipsum[1][1-12]
\lipsum[1][1-12]
\end{table}
\end{singlespace}
    
\lipsum[1][1-8]

\begin{table}[htbp]\caption{Table}\singlespacing
    \lipsum[1][1-12]
    \lipsum[1][1-12]
    \lipsum[1][1-12]
\end{table}

\lipsum[1][1-8]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: put the singlespace _inside_ the `table` not around it, or use the setspace package that handles this automatically

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the comment. I mention your first suggestion in the post. I am trying to figure out a global solution (instead of per table). Can you provide more details on your latter proposed solution? That package alone doesn't seem to fix it (when using \doublespacing for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The additional spacing is a byproduct of `\lipsum`.

You have to do nothing if you rely on `setspace`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%\doublespacing
\setstretch{1.5}

\unpacklipsum[1][1-8]

\begin{document}

1\lipsumexp

2\lipsumexp

\begin{table}[htbp]\caption{Table}
\lipsum[1][1-12]
\lipsum[1][1-12]
\lipsum[1][1-12]
\lipsum[1][1-12]
\end{table}

3\lipsumexp

\begin{table}[htbp]\caption{Table}
    \lipsum[1][1-12]
    \lipsum[1][1-12]
    \lipsum[1][1-12]
\end{table}

4\lipsumexp

\end{document}
```

Here I use `\unpacklipsum` to avoid the insertion of `\par`, that's actually the cause of your trouble.

[image]

Comment: I can replicate the spacing issue without lipsum (substitute lipsum for normal text), but using "\setstretch{1.5}" instead of linespread fixed the issue.